# Android- Firebase How to assign a child value under each ArrayList value?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an event sorter app. I'm trying to grab the friends arraylist from the database, and add the event_key under each friend value in the database.

```
final ArrayList<String> friends= new ArrayList<String>();
hello.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     friends.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey())); 
                 }

                 mDatabaseUserEvents.child(invited_list).child(event_key).setValue(true);
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });
```

However, I get an error saying that ArrayList is not compatible.

The database structure I am trying to aim for is this:

```
Events:
       -User1:
              -event_key:true
       -User2:
              -event_key:true
```

I am pretty sure I need to use a for loop, but confused on how to achieve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Firebase is a NoSQL database, it is structured as pairs of key and values. So every child is a `Map` and not an ArrayList. It's true that you can get a value from the database and store into an ArrayList but not in the way you do, because of the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method, your `friends` ArrayList will always be empty. This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called even before you are trying to add those values to that ArrayList.

If you want to set `true` for all the `event_key` coresponding to each user and assuming that `Events` node is a direct child of Firebase-database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventsRef = rootRef.child("Events");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userKey = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", userKey);
            eventsRef.child(userKey).child("event_key").setValue(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
eventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!